# user should not use previous password when reset passwod?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, passwords

i have a website and i want to restrict that the user should not use the previous 3 password as a new password when resetting password.

Comment: Then store these previous passwords per user and restrict to use them. Can't add anything more just because your question is far too broad to be answered in StackOverflow format.

Comment: oh..you want to store the previous password in db??

Comment: its cool...i just need reference and idea about that

Comment: It is up to you - where you will store these passwords. In DB, or maybe in text file, or anywhere else. But it is obvious if you doesn't store them - you are unable to determine if password being changed one of previous passwords of the same user.

Comment: which one is best ....??

Comment: You should never store the passwords in a database but store the hash of the password. Look here for more info on this subject.

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

When you store the last X password hashes, you can compare the new password hash with these old password hash and decide whether the password has already be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have store all three password in table like old_password, old_password1, old_password2.
when user requesting for changing the password fetch all three password from table
and compare them if current password is not equal with last three then update. 
I will prefer use of switch case  rather then if else log.

```
$a='old_password1';
$b='old_password2';
$c='old_password3';
$pass ='new password ';
switch ($pass){
    case $a:
        echo "nope1";
        break;
     case $b:
        echo "nope2";
        break;
     case $c:
        echo "nope3";
        break;
    default :
        echo "update password here";
}
```

Performance wise switch case is better then lots of else if chain.
Hope it will help you. Happy coding.

Comment: i have one doubt....how to store  last 3 passwords

Comment: Fire Query  and get value of all three password

Comment: what is fire query??

Comment: Oh.. fire Query means run Query and get data from the table

Answer (score 0):

Save previous hashed passwords in database and when creating new one check if it don't match previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

Store their previous passwords in the database. old_pass_1, old_pass_2 and old_pass_3.

```
submits password for update
check if new password matches with any of the field old_pass_1, old_pass_2 or old_pass_3. If not then proceed else go to %
check if old_pass_1 is empty - store old pass here and go to #
else check if old_pass_2 is empty - yes - move old_pass_1 to old_pass_2 and update old_pass_1 with old password and go to #
else check if old_pass_3 is empty - yes - move old_pass_2 to old_pass_3 and old_pass_1 to old_pass_2 and store the old pass to old_pass_1
else if none of them is empty then move move old_pass_2 to old_pass_3 and old_pass_1 to old_pass_2 and store the old pass to old_pass_1
# store the new password to the password field.
%Display message password was already used earlier by you.
```